# Is there any way to get WebdriverIO E2E testing code coverage?

Tags: automated-tests, code-coverage, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I am using **WebdriverIO** for the e2e automation testing. I would like to get the code coverage for my e2e tests. Is there any way I can get the **code coverage** for **e2e tests**?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Most automation tools now days have a plugin which can talk external code coverage services and get the stats after a test run is complete.

The steps are

- Instrument your dev src code using a popular instrumentation tool called istanbul (https://istanbul.js.org/)
- Serve the instrumented src code on your local machine
- Run E2E Tests against the instrumented src code app
- After run, the code coverage report is generated

more details: https://webdriver.io/docs/devtools-service/#capture-code-coverage

Also if you need complete details with video, Cypress has some live tutorial videos, this won't help you with wdio exactly, but you will get an overall idea of how coverage works with e2e: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Of course that's possible, see https://webdriver.io/docs/devtools-service.html#chrome-devtools-access.

Basically, instrument your code and grab the count after ech test or use browser build in feature

I created a npm module for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-coverage-service

Answer (score -3):

//This was before Component testing and other stuff. Now it is possible as guys said.
No, it is not possible. It is black box testing - your tests can't reach code of your code and check what functions are called and check code coverage.

Check [Black box testing](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/black-box-testing/) - because E2E is kind of Black box testing.